# I need to change the functions from RaisedButton to ElevatedButton please can someone fix it

Tags: flutter

Please help to change the code
I'm new to Dart & flutter and need some help with Migrating from RaisedButton to ElevatedButton. How does the styling code for the elevatedButton of this RaisedButton look like
I really need to fix this code, please can someone help I am having a hard time migrating from Raisedbutton to Elevatedbutton.I don't know what to do with padding, color, and textColor.

```
    if (widget.icon != null || widget.iconData != null) {
      textWidget = Flexible(child: textWidget);
      return Container(
        height: widget.options.height,
        width: widget.options.width,
        child: RaisedButton.icon(
          icon: Padding(
            padding: widget.options.iconPadding ?? EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: widget.icon ??
                FaIcon(
                  widget.iconData,
                  size: widget.options.iconSize,
                  color: widget.options.iconColor ??
                      widget.options.textStyle.color,
                ),
          ),
          label: textWidget,
          onPressed: onPressed,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.options.borderRadius),
            side: widget.options.borderSide ?? BorderSide.none,
          ),
          color: widget.options.color,
          colorBrightness:
              ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor(widget.options.color),
          textColor: widget.options.textStyle.color,
          disabledColor: widget.options.disabledColor,
          disabledTextColor: widget.options.disabledTextColor,
          elevation: widget.options.elevation,
          splashColor: widget.options.splashColor,
        ),
      );
    }

    return Container(
      height: widget.options.height,
      width: widget.options.width,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.circular(widget.options.borderRadius ?? 28),
          side: widget.options.borderSide ?? BorderSide.none,
        ),
        textColor: widget.options.textStyle.color,
        color: widget.options.color,
        colorBrightness:
            ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor(widget.options.color),
        disabledColor: widget.options.disabledColor,
        disabledTextColor: widget.options.disabledTextColor,
        padding: widget.options.padding,
        elevation: widget.options.elevation,
        child: textWidget,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The public docs talk about this, and it would be best if you could go read those and return here to update your question with specific problems understanding the docs at https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons

Answer (score 0):

To style an ElevatedButton use:

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: const Text('Login'),
    )
```